# How to mask information in mysql

Tags: mysql, security, random, data-masking

Let's assume that a database dump is made "production for the bank" development "where developers will work and I do not want developers to see sensitive information like social security number, credit card, phone, etc ... like could I mask this data in mysql?

Example

Original
Phone: 1111-1111

Masked with X
Phone: 11XX-XXXX

Masked randomly
Phone: 5254-7293

note: the database was written in Portuguese (my language)

[SELECT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSFC7.jpg)

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0YuG.jpg)

Comment: Please try and keep questions self-contained. Links, especially to images, can be a lot of trouble for some people but are annoying for everyone.

Comment: Use views. Then restrict access from the actual table. Then you can have the phone number column just select a bunch of random numbers for example

Comment: Since redacting this information is often a lot more trouble than it's worth, why not just randomize this data? Create a random phone number generator or use a library. There's usually a "faker" library for any programming language you might be using. Doing this in MySQL alone is usually super annoying because it doesn't have the same breadth of tools.

Comment: @dustytrash That doesn't help if you're loading a dump of data for testing purposes.

Comment: thanks tadman but I do not have enough reputation to publish images

Comment: @dustytrash it would be great to do as you mentioned but I can not change the database structure, since the bank theoretically belongs to third parties

Comment: @tadman I also thought of generating the values ​​in a random way using some generator but due to a certain validation factor this would not be possible

Comment: You're going to have to aggressively trash data if you want any sort of redaction done here. Either you replace the data, or you have a data leak.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar to what this software does but I'm looking for a free solution

https://www.imperva.com/products/data-security/data-masking/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a free version of [DataVeil data masking software](https://www.dataveil.com) that you can use. It's similar to the software you ask about in your question's comments. There are also [demo videos](https://www.dataveil.com/demo/) on the site. Disclaimer: I work for DataVeil.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to data masking, you should look into using synthetic data as an alternative for testing and development using databases that contain sensitive information. It's a relatively new approach that's under active research, so there aren't many production ready tools available. You can find a good general lit review of the latest research here: https://doi.org/10.31228/osf.io/bfqh3

Full disclosure, I work for a company that's commercializing this technology (http://tonic.ai). Please reach out if you have any questions, happy to give you a overview of how to get started with synthetic data.